# How `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding/InputEncoding` with Python?

Tags: python, .net, shell, powershell

Under Powershell v5, Windows 8.1, Python 3. Why these fails and how to fix?

```bsh
[system.console]::InputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8; 
[system.console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8; 
chcp; 
"import sys
print(sys.stdout.encoding)
print(sys.stdin.encoding)
sys.stdout.write(sys.stdin.readline())
" | 
sc test.py -Encoding utf8; 
[char]0x0422+[char]0x0415+[char]0x0421+[char]0x0422+"`n" | py -3 test.py
```

prints:

```
Active code page: 65001
cp65001
cp1251
п»ї????
```

Comment: Every program has its own stdin/stdout encoding. There's no global system setting that can override another program's settings, so whatever you set in PowerShell affects only PowerShell. Set your python stdin encoding manually, if possible. I think there should be lots of examples for that.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is there some conventions for Python? It seems to get its stdout encoding from system one. But why not stdin?

Comment: My point is that every program uses its own heuristics and logic, so whatever you set in PowerShell doesn't apply to python's handling of stdin. Well, generally. Python 3 tries to be smart and guess stdin encoding, but you can't *rely* on that, of course. As I said there should be LOTS of examples how to set stdin encoding in python.

Comment: `$OutputEncoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8`?

Answer (score 8):

You are piping data into Python; at that point Python's `stdin` is no longer attached to a TTY (your console) and won't guess at what the encoding might be. Instead, the default system locale is used; on your system that's cp1251 (the Windows Latin-1-based codepage).

Set the [`PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) to override:

> `PYTHONIOENCODING`
>   If this is set before running the interpreter, it overrides the encoding used for stdin/stdout/stderr, in the syntax `encodingname:errorhandler`. Both the `encodingname` and the `:errorhandler` parts are optional and have the same meaning as in `str.encode()`.

PowerShell doesn't appear to support per-command-line environment variables the way UNIX shells do; the easiest is to just set the variable first:

```
Set-Item Env:PYTHONIOENCODING "UTF-8"
```

or even

```
Set-Item Env:PYTHONIOENCODING "cp65001"
```

as the Windows UTF-8 codepage is apparently not *quite* UTF-8 really, depending on the Windows version and on wether or not pipe redirection is used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yet it prints then this: "Active code page: 65001 
UTF-8
UTF-8
????"

Comment: @Artyom: could you test with `sys.stdout.write(repr(sys.stdin.readline()))` please? That way we can see the contents of that line and if this is Python or Powershell getting things muddled.

Comment: Then it is '\ufeff????\n'. Powershell gets it printed correctly actually if not piped in Python. That's breaking my faith in using Python under Powershell ;)

Comment: @Artyom: so Python *received* those question marks from the pipe. This can't be Python's fault surely. Next test: `sys.stdout.write(repr(sys.stdin.buffer.readline()))`. Note the `buffer` there, you'll now get undecoded bytes.

Comment: @Artyom: Also, according to [issue #13216](https://bugs.python.org/issue13216) there are differences between UTF-8 and CP65001 that matter when using redirects, so trying to set the `PYTHONIOENCODING` to `'cp65001'` *may* matter here. Sorry, no windows systems to test this on myself.

Comment: Good way to test! Then it is "Active code page: 65001
cp65001
cp65001
b'\xef\xbb\xbf????\n'"
 Yes, still not received by Python there.

Comment: @Artyom: then this is either a bug in Python's I/O layer, *or* Powershell is not handing in UTF-8 data but question marks. The [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) at the start is not encouraging either; that's a Microsoft-ism that is entirely redundant in UTF-8 but lets MS tools distinguish between 8-bit encodings and UTF-8 when opening a file.

Comment: @Artyom: if you can find *other* tools that do handle the UTF-8 pipe correctly then I suggest you file a bug with the Python project at  http://bugs.python.org/.

Answer (score 2):

Why not embed CPython in powershell?! CPython is so easy to embed, and powershell is very good REPL to [play with .NET and COM objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/creating-.net-and-com-objects--new-object-). Here is a simple introduction to using [pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) from PowerShell. Note how encoding is automatically propagated from powershell to python.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\denfromufa> [system.console]::InputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;
PS C:\Users\denfromufa> [system.console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;
PS C:\Users\denfromufa> [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Python\Miniconda3_64b\Lib\site-packages\Python.Runtime.dll")


GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v4.0.30319     C:\Python\Miniconda3_64b\Lib\site-packages\Python.Runtime.dll


PS C:\Users\denfromufa> $gil = [Python.Runtime.Py]::GIL()
PS C:\Users\denfromufa> $sys=[Python.Runtime.Py]::Import("sys")
PS C:\Users\denfromufa> $sys.stdin.encoding.ToString()
cp65001
PS C:\Users\denfromufa> $sys.stdout.encoding.ToString()
cp65001
PS C:\Users\denfromufa> $gil.Dispose()
PS C:\Users\denfromufa> [Python.Runtime.PythonEngine]::Shutdown()
PS C:\Users\denfromufa>
```

---

[EDIT]

Here is `snek` package that was released by one of `powershell` developers for embedding `Python` in `powershell`:

https://github.com/adamdriscoll/snek

Comment: Valuable addition! Still the question not answered (looks like a bug). I wonder if pythonnet will run python scripts which work with encoding correctly. Yes, `stdin` there got encoding correctly; so looks promising

Comment: Could you post if pythonnet receives and pipes out correctly as in the question?