# Is it good practice to switch to UTF8 in Powershell by default?

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8

After reading a lot of questions about problems with output encoding in Powershell (with Python) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console#5430), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349139/utf-8-output-from-powershell#22363632), [3](https://superuser.com/questions/327492/default-powershell-to-emitting-utf-8-instead-of-utf-16), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992381/python-popen-failing-to-use-proper-encoding-in-windows-powershell#9992700), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183614/how-system-consoleoutputencoding-inputencoding-with-python), etc.) I thought why not to switch to UTF8 from beginning in my profile. Do you see any obstacles with this? Does someone use this and how successfully?

```
# Default encoding to UTF8
chcp 65001
[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
[System.Console]::InputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
```

Comment: Console codepage won't help in case you read stdio pipe in python.